# Как написать POST и PUT запрос с realtion в strapi.io на Python

Tags: python, post, requests, put, strapi

Не могу решить проблему с POST и PUT запросом в strapi.io.
Relation у меня 1 ко многим (у билета может быть 1 категория, у категории - много билетов).
GET запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "first_name": "Alex",
            "last_name": "Porter",
            "phone": "+74955978965",
            "company": "Test",
            "entry_time": null,
            "entered": false,
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "count_entry": 0,
            "createdAt": "2022-05-06T10:21:22.753Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-05-20T11:43:57.707Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-05-06T10:21:23.680Z",
            "photo": {
                "data": null
            },
            "category": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "Junior",
                        "createdAt": "2022-05-20T11:36:46.360Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2022-05-20T11:37:17.517Z",
                        "publishedAt": "2022-05-20T11:37:17.516Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Так выглядит моя функция с PUT запросом:

```
def edit_member(self, member_id, first_name, last_name, phone, category):
    url = config.SERVER + f'api/members/{member_id}?populate=%2A'
    payload = {
        'data': {
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": first_name,
                "last_name": last_name,
                "phone": phone,
            },
            "category": {
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": category
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {config.TOKEN}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

В итоге данные появляются на strapi, но теряется relation (остается пустым).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: id добавить попробуй

Comment: попробовал добавить, результат тот же, может у меня неправильная структура reqiest'а?